# How can I simplify SQL query using Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to created a simpler way for the query below.

```
SELECT 
    T1.company,
    T1.project, 
    T1.ID, 
    T1.date,
    T1.qty, 
    (
        SELECT MAX(T2.cost)
        FROM Hour_Cost  AS T2
        WHERE T2.company = T1.company AND
        T2.id = T1.ID AND
        T2.trans_date =
        (
            SELECT MAX(T3.date)
            FROM Hour_Cost AS T3
            WHERE T3.company = T2.company AND
            T3.id = T2.id AND
            T3.trans_date <= T1.date
        )
    ) AS PRICE
FROM Empl_Table AS T1
```

The query takes long hours to get the data I need. Is there a way to simplify this? I am trying to use joins but can't get the exact data I need.

Thank you for your help!

See below sample data.

Empl_Table:

```
id  date
1   5/31/2015
1   11/15/2015
1   11/15/2015
1   11/15/2015
1   12/22/2015
1   12/24/2015
1   12/25/2015
1   1/1/2016
1   1/5/2016
1   1/11/2016
1   1/18/2016
1   1/25/2016
1   4/15/2016
1   4/27/2016
2   10/5/2018
2   10/8/2018
2   10/9/2018
2   10/10/2018
2   10/11/2018
2   10/12/2018
2   2/1/2019
2   2/4/2019
2   2/5/2019
2   2/6/2019
2   2/7/2019
2   2/8/2019
2   2/11/2019
2   2/12/2019
2   2/13/2019
2   2/14/2019
2   2/15/2019
```

Hour_Cost:

```
date    id  cost
12/1/2015   1   79.53
1/1/2016    1   64.49
1/1/2018    2   69.59
1/1/2019    2   62.45
1/1/2020    2   60.37
1/1/2021    2   63.79
```

Desired results:

```
ID  date        OUTPUT
1   5/31/2015   0.00
1   11/15/2015  0.00
1   11/15/2015  0.00
1   11/15/2015  0.00
1   12/22/2015  79.53
1   12/24/2015  79.53
1   12/25/2015  79.53
1   1/1/2016    64.49
1   1/5/2016    64.49
1   1/11/2016   64.49
1   1/18/2016   64.49
1   1/25/2016   64.49
1   4/15/2016   64.49
1   4/27/2016   64.49
2   10/5/2018   69.59
2   10/8/2018   69.59
2   10/9/2018   69.59
2   10/10/2018  69.59
2   10/11/2018  69.59
2   10/12/2018  69.59
2   2/1/2019    62.45
2   2/4/2019    62.45
2   2/5/2019    62.45
2   2/6/2019    62.45
2   2/7/2019    62.45
2   2/8/2019    62.45
2   2/11/2019   62.45
2   2/12/2019   62.45
2   2/13/2019   62.45
2   2/14/2019   62.45
2   2/15/2019   62.45
```

thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest adding some sample data and providing the query logic.

Comment: `T2.trans_date = ...` - works without `TOP (1)`?

Comment: Impossible to know without access to a [MRE] and the execution plan.

Comment: @BagusTesa - `MAX()` (and other aggregate functions) will return a scalar result in the absence of a `GROUP BY`. Guaranteed to be a single value. (Compare with the common `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTab;le`.

Comment: @TN oh yeah, i missed that one. thank you.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...)` pattern to directly select the *best matching* Hour_Cost row for each Empl_Table row.

The `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` constructs are like joins to subselects. A `CROSS APPLY` is like an inner join, while an `OUTER APPLY` is like a left outer join.

```
SELECT 
    E.company,
    E.project, 
    E.ID, 
    E.date,
    E.qty, 
    HC.cost AS PRICE
FROM Empl_Table AS E
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 HC.*
    FROM Hour_Cost AS HC
    WHERE HC.company = E.company
    AND HC.id = E.id
    AND HC.trans_date <= E.date
    ORDER BY HC.trans_date DESC
) AS HC
```

This assumes that `Hour_Cost` table does not have conflicting rows with the same `company`, `id`, and `trans_date`.

For efficiency, you should ensure that the `Hour_Cost` table has an appropriate index, such as `Hour_Cost(company, id, trans_date)`. Add `INCLUDE(cost)` to the index definition to make it a *covering index* for even better performance.

Results:

| ID | date | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-05-31 | *null* |
| 1 | 2015-11-15 | *null* |
| 1 | 2015-11-15 | *null* |
| 1 | 2015-11-15 | *null* |
| 1 | 2015-12-22 | 79.53 |
| 1 | 2015-12-24 | 79.53 |
| 1 | 2015-12-25 | 79.53 |
| 1 | 2016-01-01 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-01-05 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-01-11 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-01-18 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-01-25 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-04-15 | 64.49 |
| 1 | 2016-04-27 | 64.49 |
| 2 | 2018-10-05 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2018-10-08 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2018-10-09 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2018-10-10 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2018-10-11 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2018-10-12 | 69.59 |
| 2 | 2019-02-01 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-04 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-05 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-06 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-07 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-08 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-11 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-12 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-13 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-14 | 62.45 |
| 2 | 2019-02-15 | 62.45 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HymQA6jL) for a demo.

Comment: cross apply is a lateral join, works on a row-by-row basis for each outer row.